# Unable to get the response when content-encoding is not specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, testing, testcafe

I'm trying to testcafe RequestLogger and then get the api response logged.
But it looks like I'm missing something, when the content-encoding is not specified.

It doesn't return anything in the 'else' section in the 'getLoggerBody' method, even after waiting for long.

Here's my code:

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';
import { get } from "lodash";
import zlib from "zlib";

export const getLogger = (url, method = 'GET') => RequestLogger(url, { logResponseBody: true, logResponseHeaders: true });

export const getLoggerResponseBody = logger => {
  const request = logger.requests[0];
  const contentEncoding = get(request, ['response', 'headers', 'content-encoding']);
  if (contentEncoding && contentEncoding === 'gzip') {
    const unzippedBody = zlib.gunzipSync(request.response.body);
    return JSON.parse(unzippedBody.toString());
  } else {
    return JSON.parse(request.response.body.toString());
  }
};
```

The 'request.response.body' looks like a buffer as shown in the snippet below.

> <Buffer 7b 22 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 ... 4973 more bytes>

Could you help me fix this? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to use your simplified code on the simple website. It looks like everything works as expected. It's expected that the `request.response.body` contains `Buffer` content. Please take a look at the https://testcafe.io/documentation/402769/reference/test-api/requestlogger/constructor#header article and pay attention to the `logResponseBody` and `stringifyResponseBody` sections.

I prepared a sample which demonstrates that your approach is correct in general case. Please see it:

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

export const getLogger = (url, method = 'GET') => RequestLogger(url, { logResponseBody: true, logResponseHeaders: true });

export const getLoggerResponseBody = logger => {
    const request = logger.requests[0];

    return request.response.body.toString();
};

const logger = getLogger(/.*/)

fixture `f`
    .page `http://example.com`
    .requestHooks(logger);

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click('h1');

    console.log(getLoggerResponseBody(logger));
});
```

If you would like the TestCafe Team to research your issue further, please create a sample that reproduces the issue at the following link:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml